# How to handle setResult in phone settings?

Tags: java, android

I cannot make this work, I have an application with a webview that requires permissions to access storage when downloading, I am trying that, when the user rejects permissions, my application tells them how to activate the permission by accessing the application settings.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                    Uri.fromParts("package", getActivity().getPackageName(), null));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivityForResult(intent, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

s

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Permission is granted
                myWebView.loadUrl(urlDownload);
            } else {
                
            }
            return;
        }
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                openImageChooserActivity();
            } else {
                
            }
            return;
        }
        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request.
    }
}
```

`myWebView.loadUrl(urlDownload);` this code snippet runs without problem when permission is granted from android alert but I can't control it if the user grants the permission from the settings.

Finally, a newbie question, I have seen several examples of similar codes that seem to work, but I do not understand how setResult is handled in the configurations because I do not have access to it, if for example `MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 101` how is it that android configurations know to put setResult (101) when user activates storage?